# Update row based on previous row id

Tags: sql-server

I have an update query like so

```
UPDATE myTable
SET ParentID = X
```

I need X to be the ID of the previous row that is currently being updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by "previous" row you mean the row where the id is the biggest value less than the value in  the current row, you can use the `lag()` function in SQL Server 2012 or a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE myTable
    SET ParentID = (select top 1 id
                    from mytable m2
                    where m2.id < myTable.id
                    order by id desc
                   )
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following script will be useful (Assuming that the first value not have previous value then will be NULL), you can try this **[HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/df881/4)**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  ID INT);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(10);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(20);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(30);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(40);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(50);
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(60);

/*HERE THE SCRIPT*/
WITH temp AS (
    SELECT x.ID,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.ID) AS n
    FROM TEST x
)
UPDATE t
SET t.ID = (SELECT temp.ID FROM temp WHERE temp.n = t.n - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT x.ID,
      ROW_NUMBER() over (order by x.ID) AS n
    FROM TEST x
  ) t

SELECT * FROM TEST
```

NOTE: maybe this can be solved in an easier way, but it was the first thing that occurred to me with what you have posted